# Error for iOS UI automated script "Cannot perform action on invalid element: UIAElementNil from target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()[0]"

Tags: ios, user-interface, ios-ui-automation

I am getting error for iOS UI automation as
"Cannot perform action on invalid element: `UIAElementNil` from `target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()[0]`".

My script is simply a single line

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["Yes"].tap();
```

I have labelled Yes Button in required xib file and made accessibility enabled.

Any pointer why is the error?

Answer (score 1):

Print and examine element tree if button is in place with required labels.

Sometimes short delay before tapping element helps.